# How to set Wijmo scrolling?

Tags: jquery, python, html, wijmo

I wanted help for my grid. It does not have scrolling. Can anyone help me adding the scrolling in the wijmo grid

The jquery grid table is as follows:

```
<div id="tabs-1">            
<table id="all_grid" data-bind="wijgrid: { data: data, 
 allowEditing: true, 
 allowPaging:true,
 allowColSizing:true,
 allowSorting:true,
 showFilter: true,
 pageSize:20,


 // columns: [{headerText: 'Title'}, {headerText: 'Pub Date'}, {headerText: 'Sent'},{headerText: 'Link'}],
 }">

 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: <div id="tabs-1">            
<table id="all_grid" data-bind="wijgrid: { data: data, 
 allowEditing: true, 
 allowPaging:true,
 allowColSizing:true,
 allowSorting:true,
 showFilter: true,
 pageSize:20,

 
 // columns: [{headerText: 'Title'}, {headerText: 'Pub Date'}, {headerText: 'Sent'},{headerText: 'Link'}],
 }">
 
 </table>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

In order to enable scrolling, you need to set the scrollMode property of the Wijgrid to "auto" or horizontal etc. as per your requirement. By default, it is set to none. For more details on it, you may refer to these links:

Sample: http://wijmo.com/demo/explore/?widget=Grid&sample=Scrolling

Doc link:
http://wijmo.com/wiki/index.php/Grid#scrollMode